# La versión de Visual Studio no me deja crear un WIndows Service

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Sera por la versión?? Tendré que descargar alguna plantilla?? Ya probé con una versión que esta full y si la tiene. Tengo la versión libre que Microsft te deja descargar

Comment: ¿Qué versión estás utilizando?

Comment: Eso se selecciona al momento de instalar. Intenta abrir el instalador de nuevo y seleccionar las opciones correspondientes.

Comment: Cambiaste donde dice .Net Framework 4.5?

Comment: Ya he probado con otros Frameworks desde la version 4.5 y tampoco lo trae..

Comment: Tengo la version Community 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como se indica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30689355/3200493), debes poner en el cuadro de búsqueda `Windows Service` y te aparecerá el elemento para crear el nuevo proyecto. Por alguna razón que desconozco no se muestra el elemento en el panel de la parte izquierda.

Comment: Gracias, se puso resolver de esa manera